# How to make a console text gradient in java?

Tags: java, linux, console

I haven't seen much info on how to do this, so what would be the best way to make a text gradient using java (for linux)?

Here is my best attempt at a gradient:
[failed gradient](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPeB3.png)

It's made using the jansi library, and really isn't all that special considering the fact it's limited to 9 colors.

```java
AnsiConsole.systemInstall();
        Color[] gradientColors = {Color.GREEN, Color.GREEN, Color.GREEN, Color.GREEN, Color.CYAN, Color.CYAN, Color.CYAN, Color.CYAN, Color.BLUE, Color.BLUE, Color.BLUE};
        int count = 0;
            
        
        for(String line : mainText) {
            System.out.println(Ansi.ansi().fg(gradientColors[count]).a(line));
            count++;
            if(count == 11) {
                break;
            }
}
```

This is the code I've tried (yes, I know it's really messy).

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I doubt there's a good way to make a text gradient with ANSI.

Comment: Roll your own Console window for Gradient text. [See this SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54379051/4725875).